# How to change this ajax code to long polling

Tags: javascript, ajax, long-polling

This is my ajax code so please can anyone tell me how can i change this code to long polling ?

Here is my code :-

```
var chat = {}
chat.fetchMessages = function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/ajax/chat.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { method: 'fetch' },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#chats').html(data);
    }
  }); 
}
chat.interval = setInterval(chat.fetchMessages, 1000);
```

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Also, is this the same as your question you asked 1 hr ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838715/how-to-change-from-ajax-polling-to-long-polling ? If so, you should revise your original question, rather than just asking again - [Can I re-ask a question if it hasn't been answered?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/can-i-re-ask-a-question-if-it-hasnt-been-answered) [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the next call of fetchMessage in the callback of the previous one :

```
var chat = {}
chat.fetchMessages = function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/ajax/chat.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { method: 'fetch' },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#chats').html(data);
      chat.fetchMessages(); // let's do it again
    }
  }); 
}
chat.fetchMessages(); // first call
```

Comment: Just as a note, you probably want to put some kind of time delay on the call (i.e. wrap the recursive `chat.fetchMessages();` in a `setTimeout` function. Otherwise, you run the risk of slowing down and/or crashing your entire server environment due to an overload of opening and closing connections from the ajax requests.

Comment: @War10ck Thanks for your help but i did what you said and nothing new happened it even got faster to send requests that is my new code :-

var chat = {}

chat.fetchMessages = function () {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/ajax/chat.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { method: 'fetch' },
  success: function(data) {
   $('#chats').html(data);
   $('#chatshere').scrollTop($('#chatshere')[0].scrollHeight);
   setTimeout(chat.fetchMessages(),30000);
    }
 }); 
}

chat.fetchMessages()

Comment: @Magikano Try removing the `()` in the `setTimeout` statement. It should read `setTimeout(chat.fetchMessages, 30000);`. As it is currently written the function will be evaluated immediately as the open and close parenthesis `()` represent a function call. In this case, the function should not be evaluated immediately but as a _callback_ of the `setTimeout` function. Check out this simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsNyy/) that illustrates this point.

Comment: @War10ck Thanks for your replay i did what you said but it also keeps getting request every second chat.php then after 1 second chat.php ant thats what i dont want , i want it to wait until something new comes up in the database then it gets a request , that what i thought long polling will do for me !

Comment: @Magikano Okay, that's good then. My apologies. I must have misunderstood what you were asking for. That's good that it is working though. :) Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: @War10ck thanks but now i have this code in short polling so how i can make it long polling !

Comment: @Magikano Let me see if I'm following you. You want to only make the ajax request when new chat data is available? It sounds like what you want is a _push_ service. A _push_ service is where the client stays idle. When the server gets new information it automatically pushes it to the client who receives it and takes the appropriate action. Unfortunately I have only read of such technologies. I haven't ever actually coded them. My apologies buddy but that is pretty much the extent of my knowledge on push technology.

Comment: @War10ck ok no problem thanks very much for all your replies and i will try to google "push service" and know more about it . thanks alot :)

Comment: @Magikano not a problem buddy. Hope it works out for you. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

The above code seems to work fine but this will call function immediately as a result of this it would increase the traffic and possibly for continuous long polling memory usage by the browser will increase . Try to use settimeout to keep some duration between calls made , would be good if you clear cache too . Other option would be comet or signaR .

Comment: ok i don't want it to keep requesting every second i want it to just bring all the new messages when it is available , and i tried to learn the comet but i found it very confusing and difficult to use so i want to make it with long polling because i think it is easier !

Comment: as i said it may increase your browser memory usage continously resulting in browser crash . Any other alternative could be sheepjax .

Comment: yeah because this is short polling but if it was long polling it would be better , right ?